# If I use the concept of virtual ground in a basic op amp circuit I end up with zero gain

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image]

Since no current flows in a op amp,therefore no current flows via resistor$$R_c$$,which implies that $$V_+ =0$$Using the concept of virtual ground we can say $$V_-=0$$.Now using the fact that $$V_0=A.(V_+-V_-)$$and $$V+ ,V_=0$$ we get that the $$V_0=0$$ which is incorrect.
I can't understand where I'm making a mistake. I will be thankful for even a hint.

Comment: It's not a **virtual ground**, it is a **virtual short** between the two inputs. Too many people call it virtual ground without clarifying that this is true **only** if the non-inverting input is grounded.

Comment: Indeed, i agree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assumption that V+ and V- are both equal to each other requires that the gain of the opamp be infinitely large and that the opamp be connected in a negative feedback configuration. This is because the negative feedback, with the help of the large gain, will try to equalize the two inputs.

Now when you try to use the standard differential amplifier equation,
$$V_{o}=A(V_+-V_-)$$
where \$A\$ is the opamp gain,
you make the implicit assumption that \$A\$ is not infinite. Otherwise, this equation does not mathematically make sense.

To see how the feedback network determines the operation of the opamp, consider the transfer function of an amplifier with negative feedback:
$$H=\frac{A}{1+Af}$$ where \$A\$ is the amplifier gain and \$f\$ is the gain of the feedback network. If \$A\$ is extremely large, \$1+Af\approx{}Af\$ and we get
$$H\approx\frac{1}{f}$$
Thus, the transfer function entirely depends on the feedback network.

Comment: `If A is extremely large, 1+Af≈f` nope. If \$A\$ is extremely large then \$1+Af\approx Af\$.

Comment: Whoops, thanks for the catch.

Comment: @lettersized ,so basically your saying that we run into an indeterminate form 'infinity *zero' . So we attack it from another angle? Am I correct?

Comment: @Yasir That's kind of what I'm getting at. A real opamp does not have infinite gain, and the equation Vo=A(V+ - V-) holds. Let's say you did have a perfect, linear differential amplifier with infinite gain with no feedback. Then that equation still holds...except now your output is infinite. But if you add negative feedback, the infinite gain forces the two inputs to be equal in order to make the output finite. That is, in order for Vo = A(V+ - V-) to be finite with A infinite, we NEED (V+ - V-)=0. And at this point, we need to redo the analysis with this new assumption of V+ = V-.

Comment: @LetterSized 3,hearty thanks bro.

Answer (score 3):

Using virtual ground does indeed make you arrive at the correct answer. No current flows through \$R_c \$

$$i_{R_C}=0 \text{A} \Rightarrow V_+ = 0\text{V}. $$

Using **virtual ground** we have $$ V_- = V_+ = 0\text{V}. $$

The current flowing through R1 is: $$i_{R_1}=\frac{V_\text{in}-V_-}{R_1}=\frac{V_\text{in}}{R_1} $$

The current flowing through Rf. $$ i_{R_f}=\frac{V_--V_o}{R_f}=\frac{-V_o}{R_f}$$

Those two currents are the same. Setting up the equation $$ i_{R_1}=i_{R_f} \Leftrightarrow \frac{V_\text{in}}{R_1}=\frac{-V_o}{R_f}$$
Recall that the gain is given as: \$A_v=\frac{V_o}{V_\text{in}} \$. Manipulating the equation we finally end up with $$A_v = \frac{V_o}{V_\text{in}}=-\frac{R_f}{R_{1}} $$

Comment: Thanks Carl, i agree with you but my issue is what's wrong with my approach?

Comment: @YasirSadiq in order to have an ideal virtual ground, A has to be infinity. What's infinity times zero? Or alternatively, if A is not infinity, then V- isn't 0 volts.

Comment: Infinity times zero is undefined. Now what i get from the answers is that we attack the problem from another angle, like what Carl has done.

Answer (score 2):

> I can't understand where I'm making a mistake.

The following formula,
$$
V_o=A\ (V_+ - V_-)
$$

is for open-loop (i.e. no feedback present) opamp circuits and \$A\$ is the open-loop gain of the opamp which can be extremely large. Don't mix this with \$A\$ shown in your circuit.

But your circuit introduces a feedback:

[image]

[Img Source](https://paginas.fe.up.pt/%7Efff/eBook/MDA/Teo_realim.html)

Remember the basic feedback theory:

$$
A_V=\frac{V_o}{V_i}=\frac{A}{1+\beta A}
$$

If there were no \$\beta\$ (i.e. open loop) then you'd be correct since the gain would be \$A\$ (open-loop gain).

So, with feedback, output-to-input voltage gain will be \$A_V=-R_f/R_1\$.

Comment: Vo=A(V+ - V-) applies whether there is feedback or not (as long as the opamp isn't saturated). The difference with feedback is that  V+ - V- depends on Vo itself.

Comment: @LetterSized could you please show me an example where that formula applies to an opamp circuit with feedback? Remember the definition of A (open-loop gain): *The gain of the opamp when there's no positive or negative feedback.*

Comment: If you consider the inverting amplifier in the question (and using the picture's labeling), Vo=A(V+ - V-). V+ = 0 because it is connected to ground. So now Vo = AV-.  Also, V- = (Vo-V1) * R1/(R1 + Rf) + V1 using a voltage divider equation. Plugging this into the first equation, we have Vo = A(Vo-V1) * R1/(R1+Rf) + AV1. Now solving for Vo/V1, we get Vo/V1 = A(Rf/(R1+Rf)) / (1-AR1/(R1 + Rf)). Simplify and make the large A assumption and you get: Vo/V1 = -Rf/R1. Let me know if I made a mistake.

Comment: Looks like I did make a mistake, I missed a minus sign. We should have Vo = -AV- and thus Vo = A(Vo-V1) * R1/(R1+Rf) + AV1 should be Vo = -A(Vo-V1) * R1/(R1+Rf) - AV1. Proceeding from there will give Vo/V1 = -A(Rf/(R1+Rf)) / (1+AR1/(R1 + Rf)). Making the large A assumption gives the correct answer.

Comment: @LetterSized In terms of math, yes, you are correct. But technically, we don't use the differential amplifier equation when there's a positive or negative feedback. Because the both inputs will be equal: \$V+ = V- = 0\$. This is what feedback does, you know. An opamp is nothing different from a differential amplifier with very large gain when there's no feedback. But it turns into a stabilizer which keeps both inputs equal when there's a feedback. You got what I'm trying to say?

Comment: Thank you Rohat and Lettersized, @Lettersized did you assume infinite input impedance of the op amp in your analysis?

Comment: @Yasir You are correct, I did assume infinite input impedance. If you did not, then you would need to include the effect of the resistor Rc (shown in your diagram).

Comment: @Rohat V+ = V- = 0 only if the gain of the opamp is infinite. In which case I agree that the equation Vo = A(V+ - V-) makes no sense. However, the gain of an opamp is NOT infinite in practice, however it is very large. The analysis I did above assumes a noninfinite gain with negative feedback. The gain of the opamp itself does not change with feedback, but rather the gain of the total circuit changes, according to the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of a virtual short between the two inputs of an op-amp is often presented to mean:

$$V_+ = V_-$$

But in reality, the two are not, general **exactly** equal. They are close enough to calculate the currents through the resistors in the circuit with only a very, very small error, but not close enough to draw the conclusion that

$$V_{out} = A_{OL}(V_+-V_-) = A_{OL} \times 0 = 0$$

The very, very, small error voltage, when multiplied by the very large \$A_{OL}\$ becomes significant.

It would be more accurate statement regarding the virtual ground would be that in general

$$V_+ \approx V_-$$